# Where to define schema.org itemtype for Article type: html, body, or div tag?

Tags: schema.org

I have article pages where the only content on the page is the article. When marking up pages with schema.org microdata, is it best to define the itemscope and itemtype at the very top in the `<html>` tag? Or in the `<body>` tag? Or a `<div>` in the body? Or does it not matter?

Example of defining in `<html>` tag:

```
<html lang="en" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
<body>
    <div>
    <span itemprop="name">How to Tie a Reef Knot</span>
    ...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Versus a `<div>` in the body:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
        <span itemprop="name">How to Tie a Reef Knot</span>
        ...
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is one better than the other in terms of SEO? It seems like it would be best to define it as close to the top of the page as possible (ie, `<html>` tag) so the search engine spiders pick it up immediately.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect this very page, you will find that the html tag does indeed include schema.org metadata

```
<html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/QAPage">
```

Not everyone does this, but stackoverflow is a top 100 website- take that for what its worth.

Obviously, you will want schema.org metadata throughout the page as well.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't matter, in the sense that either will work and neither is "wrong". Where you put these things depends very much on what information's on your page, and how it's arranged (e.g., some schemas can't go inside certain other ones). However, though it's actually implied, you might want to put `WebPage` on the body element, be more specific from there on down through your page code.

There's absolutely no difference in terms of SEO, partly because it doesn't matter if the microdata is parsed a fraction of a microsecond earlier, and partly because only a [few select bits of microdata](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=1088472&parent=21997&ctx=topic) are currently used by major search engines (of which `Article` isn't one), and Google have [explicitly stated there's no effect on ranking](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OolDzztYwtQ) (yet).

Answer (score 0):

You need to put that on *div* tag as your article is enclosed under it at the lowest level..so when a search engine spider will crawl your page, it can more appropriately index your article content..

Although your pages contain only articles but still they may contain other portions such as menus, author information, etc.